# Scrapy: CSS selector only extracting first two rows from table and I want every rows

Tags: python, web-scraping, scrapy, scrape

I am trying to extract text from all td of a table from the below page. I am using CSS selector for this but somehow it not giving any output. I double-checked my CSS selector script in the browser inspect it works there but not in Scrapy.

HTML LInk: https://trusting-sinoussi-0dbf65.netlify.app/

[image]

In this HTML page I got two tables with same name, first one has nothing in it and second one has all data.
And this is my scrapy code for selecting the tr and then extracting td's text. There is more than one table so I used the summary attribute to select the table. I am using for loop to extract td's from all the tr. So, in variable courses, I scraped till all tr and then passed that to for loop to extract td from each tr.
but somehow output only shows for first tr only it is not selecting all the tr from this table

> > When I extract using

```
response.css('tr').extract()
```

OUTPUT includes only first two tr

But I want all td's text inside each tr so I tried to use td instead of tr

```
response.css('td.dddefault ::text').extract()
```

then it returns all the td from the table.
**But I am not able to understand that when using tr as ectracting tag it only outputs first 2 rows values??? why? **

```
def course_scrap(self, response):
        print('course slected')
        courses = response.css('table.datadisplaytable[summary="This layout table is used to present the course found"] tr')

        for course in courses:
            trs = course.css('td.dddefault ::text').extract()

        print(trs)
```

Answer (score 1):

To get the first actual row use:

```
table.datadisplaytable[summary="This layout table is used to present the course found"] tr:nth-child(3)
```

Second:

```
table.datadisplaytable[summary="This layout table is used to present the course found"] tr:nth-child(4)
```

First two tr's are headers.

The same approach can be used to get a shorter table locator:

```
.datadisplaytable:nth-of-type(2)
```

Comment: Did this work for you? It's not working.  css selector only extracts first two tr it does not extract every tr. and I want to extract every tr

Comment: Do you mean it extracts only 2021 Fall and Computer Science rows?

Comment: Check this `table.datadisplaytable[summary="This layout table is used to present the course found"] tr:nth-child(4)>.dddefault:nth-of-type(1)` and `table.datadisplaytable[summary="This layout table is used to present the course found"] tr:nth-child(4)>.dddefault:nth-of-type(2)`

Comment: Yes it only extract those two rows

Comment: it throws an error as other tr does not exist in the scraped data.

Comment: Try this:`.datadisplaytable:nth-of-type(2) tr>td`

Comment: Hmm, if you want to print everything move print statement to the same indent as trs, under trs

Comment: But print does not play any role here, as we are not getting all tr when extract it so print will print [] if I put it inside the for loop

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/231150/discussion-between-uday-posia-and-vitaliis).

Comment: Print doesn't play any role doesn't mean you should place it anywhere you like @Uday Posia, right?

Answer (score 0):

This should fetch you the numbers and their concerning texts out of that table from that site:

```
class TrustingSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = "trusting"
    start_urls = ['https://trusting-sinoussi-0dbf65.netlify.app/']

    def parse(self,response):
        for item in response.xpath("//table[@class='datadisplaytable'][./tbody]//tr[./td]"):
            td_first = item.xpath(".//td[@class='dddefault']/text()").get()
            td_second = item.xpath(".//td[@class='dddefault'][@text-align]/text()").get()
            yield {"Number":td_first,"Text":td_second}
```

First few results:

```
051 CS Co-op Work Term #1
052 CS Co-op Work Term #2
053 CS Co-op Work Term #3
054 CS Co-op Work Term #4
055 CS Co-op Work Term #5
100 Introduction to Computers
110 Prog & Problem Solving
115 Object-Oriented Design
201 Intro to Digital System
203 Java Programming and Apps
207 Building Interactive Gadgets
210 Data Structures & Abstractions
215 Web and Database Programming
261 Methods in Numerical Analysis
280 Risk and Reward in Information
310 Discrete Computal Structure
320 Intro Artificial Intelligence
```

Comment: I want all tr's text data not only first two

Comment: It prints all of them.

Comment: For some reason its not working in my spider

Comment: Run it as it is to see the results. If you have gone somewhere wrong within your spider that is completely different thing. This solution addresses what you have asked for.

Comment: I am actually getting to this page after going through multiple pages.  from this page I want to extract data. But for some reason it putting same code only extracting first 2 rows only. Do you have any idea what could be my mistake.